# anchors not clickable on div float

Tags: html, css

In the code below the fancy anchor cannot be clicked due to float: right attribute.
Suggestion of repairing this. I need float right so when window shrinks the links go left with the window.

```css
.links {
  float: right;

}

.default {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: none;
}

  .standard {
  color: green;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div class="links">
   <a id="standard" class="default" href="#">standard</a>
   <a id="fancy" class="standard" href="#">fancy</a>
  </div>
```

Comment: See this code:http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=pOLoxL9KFa

Comment: No problems here... I think the "result" pane titel in jsfiddle might be covering your link?

Comment: Its clickable. I had check after added margin from top http://jsfiddle.net/966naq5e/13/

Comment: I have this problem in my browser...

Comment: Which browser you are using?

Comment: hmm, clickable in fiddle but in my app still cant click on it, even after adding the margins

Comment: There might be something else covering it. Try adding a right margin to  your floated div to nudge it over a bit... if the link becomes clickable then there is certainly something in the way.

Comment: tried also in firefox, same result..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here what can you do is:

1) check first by adding border attribute to the anchor so that you can see till where your anchor is floating.
2) use firefox 3d view so that the z-index will be visible and you can easily see what is overlapping your anchor.
4) as @pschueller has mentioned it is working fine in jsfiddler and the right pane is overlapping it from clickable

there is no issue with the float